# VS Code TypeScript suggestions unexpected

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, typechecking

Code examples:

```js
export interface PluginMapWithParams {
  foo: {
    foo1?: string
    foo2?: number
  }
  bar: {
    bar1?: string
    bar2?: number
  }
}

export type PluginStyle1 = {
  [Name in keyof PluginMapWithParams]: [Name, PluginMapWithParams[Name]?]
}[keyof PluginMapWithParams]

export type PluginStyle2 = {
  [Name in keyof PluginMapWithParams]: { name: Name; params?: PluginMapWithParams[Name] }
}[keyof PluginMapWithParams]

export const pluginStyle1: PluginStyle1 = ['bar', {}]

export const pluginStyle2: PluginStyle2 = {
  name: 'bar',
  params: {},
}
```

`pluginStyle1` suggestions shows all four params includes `foo`'s. Besides, if you select `foo1` or `foo2`, VS Code throws a type check error which is expected. But I prefer that VSCode doesn't suggest `foo1` and `foo2`.

`pluginStyle2` works all as expected.

How can I make `PluginStyle1`'s suggestions as same as `PluginStyle2` or is it can not be done.